# Android circle image listview

Tags: android, listview, geometry

Hi I'm looking for circle image ListView not as background, but ListView with loaded images that is in circle shape.
I have researched it and found that ListView  is vertical or horizontal... :( ,
I looked also at Radial and gallery but didn't find real list  in circle shaped ( not animation)  any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean, even a crude drawing would help, as listviews are by nature rectangular.

Comment: probably you are looking for a carousel

Comment: do you need a carousel. ?https://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/wiki/Carousel. using renderscript

Comment: drawing is not what I'm looking for , or u are telling me that i can draw ListView?

Comment: What I need is a ListView  loaded with images in a circle shape.

Answer (score 0):

finally i think i found an example :
http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples/Circle-Launcher

with CircleListView :)

Answer (score 0):

refer the below code

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return; 
    }

    Bitmap b = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP 
        && drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        ((VectorDrawable) drawable).draw(canvas);
        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBitmap(b);
        drawable.draw(c);
    } 
    else {
        b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);
}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


    return output;
}
}
```